# Is this a breadboard?

Tags: breadboard

I am a software developer who wants to learn more about how Computers work at a lower level.  I did GCSE Electronics 16 years ago.

I have bought an Electronics starter kit, which contains [this component](http://www.eio.com/p-23783-velleman-ecl-h-eurocard-full-line-39-x-63-fr4.aspx).  The shop assistant described it as a Breadboard but after a bit of Googling I believe it is a PCB as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurocard_%28printed_circuit_board%29).

It was part of a starter kit.  Do I have to solder components onto this board in order to test circuits or can I just plug them in like with a breadboard?

I realise that this is a basic question but I have spent some time Googling.

Comment: Pictures of breadboards here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadboard and also this site's logo motif (between the search box and Ask Question button in the upper portion of the page) is also a breadboard. ;-)

Comment: @shimofuri - note that what you link to has the qualifier "solderless" in it's name.  Some people do also call the premade generic PCB boards that others would call "proto boards" "breadboards" - and not inaccurately, given the originas of the term.

Comment: I'd consider that to be a "solderable perf board" but some may say that a true "perf board" does not have connected bus lines as the one you linked does. (A "perf board" with no copper pads would be for wire-wrap applications, whereas a "solderable perf board" would be for soldering components and running small gauge wire to each connection point.)

Comment: I came across this question five years late, and the link to the component in question shows something that is definitely not a breadboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's a PCB that you solder components to. You'll need to get a breadboard; small ones are cheap and widely available.

Comment: Thanks.  I know that soldering is used to secure components.  Can you confirm that I have to solder components to this board even if I was just doing some testing?

Comment: @w0051977 You have to solder things to a PCB not just to secure (mechanically) the components but also to make a circuit - that is, make a connection for electrons to pass through. Without electrons movement, no electronics. ;-)

Comment: .. and if the PCB has just round solder pads without connections between them, you'll need wires between them to make connections.

Comment: @pjc50, thanks.  I posted a link showing a picture of the board in the question.  It looks like there is copper linking all the holes.  Therefore I believe that I do not need wires.  Can you confirm that I am right?

Comment: You will probably need some wires too, because pre-made connections are not always what you need.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by: "because pre-made connections are not always what you need".  Thanks.

Comment: @w0051977 I don't want to sound harsh, but I think that you'll need to do a lot more research than you're currently doing to be able to decide if the pre-made connections fit or not. Usually on this type of boards (and they're called [stripboards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stripboard), you cut the unneeded connections. Otherwise you'll only be able to do very basic things like turn on an LED. IF you're going to be using any ICs at all, you're going to need to cut the connections and use wires to make connections you need.

Comment: @w0051977 Also there's a magic word that you need to learn  how to use very quickly and it's `datasheet`. Let's take a simple IC like 74HC000. Put into your favorite search engine `74HC000 datasheet` and you should get countless results pointing you to the datasheet for the device. It will have the device's pinout and it will tell you exactly what kind of inputs it expects. The pattern on the PCB you have isn't going to match pinout for any IC, so you'll need to cut the tracks until you get something that will b able to accept the device.

Comment: @AndrejaKo,apologies if the question is a bit basic.  I have two books to read.  Perhaps I thought I was more knowledgeable about this subject than I actually am.

Comment: @w0051977 No need to apologize! Just be sure to take some time to think about what you think you know, what you actually know and what it is exactly that you have on your bench. Many experienced people forget that and the result is usually burned components. Also don't forget: If you aren't sure about something, ask! It's free.